# Loop in a class and writing to a txt file

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out a way to store songdata as a list in a .txt. The method I am using seems to be storing the values somewhere, but its not writing them to the file. I also am trying to insert a loop into it so I can keep entering "songs" instead of only one. I haven't used classes before and I cant quite grasp how it would be done. I maybe am going about it wrong and need to reformat parts? Any advice would be awesome.

```
class Song:
    def __init__(self,song,chart,member):
        self.song = song
        self.chart = chart
        self.member = member

    def __str__(self):
        return self.song + " topped the charts at " + str(self.chart)+ " band memebers include " + str(self.member)
songdata = Song(input("song"),input("chart spot"), input("bandemember"))

def readstring(f, line):
    string = line.strip('\r\n')
    return string

def writestring(f, string):
    f.write(string)


with open("string.txt", "a+", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    cont = "Y"
    while cont.upper() == "Y":
        d = input(songdata)
        if d != "q":
            string = " "+d
            writestring(f, string)
        else:
            print("saving.....")
            break

    f.seek(0)
    for line in f:
        print(readstring(f,line))
f.close()
```

Comment: Why do you need `writestring(f, string)` if `f.write(string)` is doing exactly the same ting? Btw, do not `f.close()`, because `with` closes it automatically.

Comment: Execute your code with python3.5, it does write strings to file.Maybe it is just not doing what you want?

Comment: Seems to be working but when I open the txt file there is nothing there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of notes:

- Because you only initialised the class once when you request the information from you user in the code  `d = input(songdata)`, the prompt from `input` will always display the same thing after the first time.
- The reason why nothing is being written to file is probably because the response from `d=...` is always blank from the user. You requested the song information when you initialised the class (which you only did once), but never wrote that to file (instead you wrote `f.write(string)`, where `string=" "+d`)
- As mentioned in the replies, you don't really need a specific function to write to file when you can just call the file descriptors `write()` method.

I've re-written some of your code (the writing to file parts) below. I assumed you wanted the user to be able to exit the program at any time by entering in the key sequence `q`, and have done so accordingly. You can make something more nifty with generators I believe, but this isn't related to the problem:

```
class Song:
    """
    song class
    """

    def __init__(self, song, chart, member):
        self.song = song
        self.chart = chart
        self.member = member

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.song
                + " topped the charts at "
                + str(self.chart)
                + " band memebers include "
                + str(self.member)
                + '\n'
               )

def main():

    with open("string.txt", "a+", encoding="utf-8") as fd:

        #Loop until user requests to stop
        #Key sequence to stop = 'q'
        while(1):

            #Get user input
            prompt = ">>\t"
            in_song = input("song" + prompt)
            if (in_song == 'q'):
                break

            in_chart_spot = input("chart spot" + prompt)
            if (in_chart_spot == 'q'):
                break

            in_band_mem = input("band members" + prompt)
            if (in_band_mem == 'q'):
                break

            #Create the class
            song_data = Song(in_song, in_chart_spot, in_band_mem)

            #Write out the data
            fd.write(str(song_data))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you, your explanation is very helpful.